# Android app Install button not working in Mobilefirst App Center

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I have an Android app published in IBM Mobilefirst App Center where-in users can download and install the app to their devices. We don't have any problem for the past 1 year. Recently, we have this issue which the Install button is not working anymore even if you press for so many times. I tried to copy the APK file via bluetooth going to my device and install the app successfully.

What goes wrong with the App Center Install button? Why the app is not downloading anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been recent fixes in MobileFirst 6.3-7.1 related to AppCenter and the version of Chrome installed on the Android devices.

See the changelogs here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/

The recommended solution is to upgrade to the latest iFix level of your product version. You can download the iFix from IBM Fix Central.

Comment: Hi Idan, Thanks for the response. Aside from installing the latest iFix, is there a work around that we can do at the moment as we are now on SIT stage and upgrading the iFix will take some time. Our current version is   IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0.0.00-20160307-1716 .

Comment: I am not sure. You can contact IBM Support (by opening a PMR) to see if there is anything to do.

Comment: Thanks Idan. I found a workaround for this issue. Instead of using Chrome browser, I downloaded an alternative (UC Browser) and it works fine. With this, I can let my users to use this first while planning for the iFix upgrade.

Comment: Yes, for the moment while iFix has not been installed. I will get my Infra folks to upgrade our version. Thanks

Comment: As an alternative workaround, instead of using the "installers.html" page, you can tell your users to use the "inst.html" page in the Application Center, until you get the fix installed.  This is a simplified version of the installer page, mostly intended to work with older or non-standard browsers, but it will work in this case too.  It doesn't look as nice as the normal "installers.html" page, but it should at least get your Chrome users past this issue for now.